# How to keep running multiple geth nodes running on multiple VMs continously?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have 50 VMs and I installed geth on every VM. Now I need to run geth on each VM by doing ssh on each VM. So, I am facing one problem with this when I start a geth node on VM by ssh it starts at that time but, when I come out of ssh it stops. How should I keep the geth process running on VM continously even if I come out of ssh from that VM?

Comment: What OS are you running on your VMs? `screen` may be your best bet here

Comment: I have Ubuntu-16.04 running on each VM. @TC8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run our private nodes on Ubuntu VMs through `screen` - this provides an environment which can run on after you close the SSH connection. You could also use it to run multiple geth instances on the same VM, if you felt like it (just create multiple datadirs and use unique ports for each instance)

See the manual [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) for full info, but some high level features I'd mention are as follows:

- You can configure a custom `/etc/screenrc` file to preload geth, log files etc in individual tabs within screen nice and easily. You can then copy this file to each VM and run `screen` in a terminal; once geth is running correctly press `ctrl + a, d` to detach from the session and it'll continue running in the background
- include `autodetach on` in your screenrc file to ensure that the process carries on even if your SSH connection cuts out unexpectedly
- see [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=55618) for some custom `screenrc` formatting to make your tabs prettier - and easier to manage

Answer (score 0):

Use docker container with dynamic ports
you can use docker compose similar to something [like this setup](https://github.com/seemywingz/go-ethereum/blob/develop/private-net/docker-compose.yml)
and then `docker-compose up --scale node=200` without having to manually configure each instance